# How do I modify an attribute across all rows in a table?

Tags: php, mysql, database, algorithm

My apologies for asking such a novice question but, I need help building a script using either PHP or directly in MySQL that can do the following:

1. Take the values of a column in a table (text)
2. Change them into capitalized words (from "this is a title" to "This Is A Title")
3. Replace the old values (uncapitalized) with the new values (capitalized).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. MySQL doesn't have a function like Oracle's initcap - you have to [create the function yourself](http://ushastry.blogspot.com/2009/06/mysql-initcap-function.html):

   ```
   DELIMITER $$
   DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS `test`.`initcap`$$

   CREATE FUNCTION `initcap`(x char(30)) RETURNS char(30) CHARSET utf8
   BEGIN

     SET @str='';
     SET @l_str='';

     WHILE x REGEXP ' ' DO
       SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(x, ' ', 1) INTO @l_str;
       SELECT SUBSTRING(x, LOCATE(' ', x)+1) INTO x;
       SELECT CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(@l_str,2)))) INTO @str;
     END WHILE;

     RETURN LTRIM(CONCAT(@str, ' ', CONCAT(UPPER(SUBSTRING(x,1,1)),LOWER(SUBSTRING(x,2)))));

   END$$

   DELIMITER ;
   ```

   Mind that the text length on the parameter is as long as your longest text field.
2. Use an [UPDATE statement](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html):

   ```
   UPDATE TABLE 
      SET text_column = initcap(text_column)
   ```

Comment: @prgmatic, the benefit to @OMG Ponies's solution is that if you ever need the `initcap()` function again, you will have it accessible without having to write a quick one-use PHP script.

Comment: @OMG Ponies, you should probably cite sources when copying other people's work. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Comment: @smotchkkiss: I did - I linked to a more concise blog where it says "create the function yourself"

Comment: @OMG Ponies +1. My bad, sorry I missed that.

Comment: This is PERFECT. thank you, @OMG Ponies. And thanks smotchkiss for the added feedback.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a function that is native to MySQL, so using PHP's [`ucwords`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) might save us some time.

**Note:** This will run a single `UPDATE` query for each row in your table.

```
<?php

  $r = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM users");
  while($u = mysql_fetch_object($r)){
    $r2 = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET name=".ucwords($u->name)." WHERE id={$u=>id}");
  }

?>
```

Comment: +1: For least coding impact, but that's potentially a lot of data to transfer over the wire, capitalize appropriately, and then send back.

Answer (score 1):

Select your rows with SQL along the lines of:

`SELECT <string> FROM <table> [WHERE <field> = <whatever>]`

Update the string using PHP's `ucwords()` function:

`$UpperCaseString = ucwords($lowercase);`

Update each record:

`UPDATE <table> SET <fieldname> = <UpperCaseString> WHERE id=<id>`

Answer (score 0):

What you'll want to do is fetch all the values, and for each one, run the PHP function [ucwords](https://www.php.net/ucwords) on it. Code sample coming shortly...

EDIT: @smotchkkiss beat me to it -- use his code :-)